# Microsoft Teams for Mac (new) stuck on "Restart Teams" as soon as it opens

Tags: ms-teams

Since a day or two ago, every time I open "*Microsoft Teams (work or school)*"  (the "new" Microsoft Teams app, not the "classic" app) on a MacBook Pro (MacOS Ventura 13.5.1), it gets stuck on a black/white screen that simply says:

> [image]
>
> **Restart teams**

Previously, it worked fine. No matter how many times I restart Teams (including Force Quit, full restart, etc), it shows the same message.

There's no clue whatsoever about what the actual problem might be, or error code, or anything I could search on or use to debug this. It's a completely blank screen apart from "Restart teams" below the cutesy graphic of jaunty ⚠️ alert signs.

What can I do? (apart from not use Teams, which, sadly, isn't an option)

Answer (score 2):

I found a few different guides about clearing the Teams app cache. Most of them didn't work, but [this one did](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/teams-administration/clear-teams-cache#clear-the-cache-in-teams-for-macos):

- Close Teams
- Do these commands in the terminal:

  > ```
  > rm -rf ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.com.microsoft.teams
  > rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.teams2
  > ```
- Restart Teams again. This time, it worked

Comment: This is the suggestion that we also give where I work.